# Displaying elements inside an array list with a messagebox

Tags: c#, silverlight, arraylist

I have an array list called str, i want to see the elements inside that array list, how should I use a messagebox to display that?

p.s. displaying the first field of the element is also fine

example code(a method I created to retrieve data from api:

```
void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

                string[] split1 = Regex.Split(response, "},{");
                List<string> pri1 = new List<string>(split1);
                pri1.RemoveAt(0);
                string last = pri1[pri1.Count() - 1];
                pri1.Remove(last);

                str = pri1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ArrayList is not supported in Silverlight. What kind of list do you have?

Comment: sure its supported i'm using it right now, wat do u mean wat kind?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181800/silverlight-and-arraylist

Comment: What Silverlight version do you use? Can you paste some code?

Comment: I'm using silverlight 4 so maybe the older silverlight versions doesn't support

Comment: Any chance you could paste some code?

Comment: @Alex - I agree with GJJ.  The list that you linked to includes `KeyValuePairs` and I use them all the time.  Perhaps it's an older version list?

Comment: You mean generic KeyValuePair<Tkey, TValue>, right? This class is present in Silverlight.

Comment: @GJJ - hmm.... I can see List<T>, not ArrayList :).

Comment: @Alex isnt that how u declare an ArrayList? :P sorry new to this so am not too good with terminology and such

Comment: ArrayList is non-generic list, that exists in full framework. I also updated my answer, made it more relevant to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show comma delimited values:

```
var list = new List<string> { "tes1", "test2", "test3" };

var message = string.Join(",", list);
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

**[Update]**

A few enhancements you could make in your code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var response = "asdf},{asaaa},{shf";
    var split = Regex.Split(response, "},{");

    var elements = split
        .Skip(1)
        .Take(split.Length - 2)
        .ToList();

    var message = string.Join(",", elements);
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: @GJJ - I actually tested this code before pasting i there. Updated the answer with the full test.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox.Show(String.Join(" ", str) but are you really sure that you want this? I mean wouldn't it be more attractive to present that list inside an ItemsControl shown inside a Silverlight ChildWindow?

```
<ChildWindow>
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding str}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl
</ChildWindow>
```

Comment: i'm just using this messagebox to check if all items have been retrieved successfully from an api i am using

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
    public void PrintList(IList<object> list)
    {
        string printString = "List Elements";

        foreach (object o in list)
        {
            // Add the fields you want to show here
            printString += "\n" + o.ToString();
        }

        MessageBox.Show(printString);
    }
```

For your implementation, replace `object` with your class that stores the information you've retreived from the API and add the fields you want to see to the `printString += ...` line.

Answer (score 0):

Linq adds flexibility to the desired format:

```
var list = new List<string>{"one","two", "three"};

var consolidatedList = list.Aggregate((s1,s2) => String.Format("{0} {1}",s1,s2));
//consolidatedList = "one two three"

MessageBox.Show(consolidatedList)
```